# How to show Cordova-media-capture video feed in a DIV?

Tags: javascript, cordova, intel-xdk

I´m developing an application with Intel XDK and I can open the video-camera through cordova-media-capture but I need to open the video feed in a DIV.

I tried this tutorial:
https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/06/05/cordova-sample-capture-and-display-video/

But still opens the video-camera as a different app

How can I achieve it?
Can anybody give me other example?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

See Cordova CanvasCamera plugin at   https://www.npmjs.com/package/com.virtuoworks.cordova-plugin-canvascamera

The purpose of the plugin is to capture video to preview camera in a web page's canvas element. Allows to select front or back camera and to control the flash.

There is a try out at:https://github.com/VirtuoWorks/CanvasCameraDemo

Comment: cordova-plugin-camera-preview also a good plugin to place video preview in HTML elements. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-camera-preview Check out their sample app. :)

Comment: Thank you Michael, I can make it work but I can't see where the feed (camera video preview) is assigned to a canvas.